# Drawing graph in python3 with data enclosed in list

Tags: python-3.x, plot

I used function 'plt.bar' to draw graph about sum of dice twice thrown.
and it's value exist from 2 to 12.
Since function plt.bar use index of value in list for its X-axis, graph goes wrong.
How can I change value of X-axis?

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmGGE.png)

Comment: In my understanding `plt.bar` requires an explicit sequence of values for positioning the bars... `plt.bar(np.arange(2,13), your_data)`

Comment: Are you using `range(6)` because that'll return values from 0 to 5 for each dice, which gives you an answer between 0 and 10. Try `range(1,7)` for values between 1 and 6 inclusive.

Comment: Thank you for share your knowledge, both of you. It helps me a lot. Thank you.